# WebViewer Android Action Bar ссылка на html

Tags: java, android, action, android-webview

Пробую работать над WebViewer, немного запутался. Прошу помощи Гуру)

`menu_main.xml` (Папка `menu`):

```
<item android:id="@+id/pick_action_provider"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_akk"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Overflow" >
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_vk"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_vk"
            android:title="@string/menu_vk"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_shop"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_shop"
            android:title="@string/menu_shop"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_map"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_m"
            android:title="@string/menu_map"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_google"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_g"
            android:title="@string/menu_google"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_site"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_site"
            android:title="@string/menu_site"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Есть `MainFragment.java`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    // action bar menu behaviour
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.menu_share:
            startShareActivity(getString(R.string.app_name), mShare);
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_vk:
            Intent vkIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://сайт.ру"));
            startActivity(vkIntent);
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_map:
            Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://сайт.ру"));
            startActivity(mapIntent);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_google:
            Intent googleIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://сайт.ру"));
            startActivity(googleIntent);
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_shop:
            Intent shopIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://сайт.ру"));
            startActivity(shopIntent);
            return true;



        case R.id.menu_site:
            Intent siteIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://сайт.ру"));
            startActivity(siteIntent);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Все работает, но открывается в браузере по умолчанию.

Можно ли  в MainFragment.java указать  ссылку на HTML находящуюся уже в папке assets типа: `file:///android_asset/home.html`?

Вариант:

```
case R.id.menu_shop:
            Intent shopIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/home.html"));
            startActivity(shopIntent);
            return true;
```

Не работает...

**Пример**
[image: WebViewer Android Action Bar ссылка на html]

Comment: Ничего не понятно. У вас какое-то `WebView` есть  разметке и в нём надо отобразить ваш `Html`?.. Если так, то вы даже не пытаетесь же...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите, чтобы ваш `WebView` загрузил какой-то `URL`, нужно его просто попросить: Напишите *ВебВью, загрузи УРЛ*. Перевод на `Java`:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/home.html");
```

Магия, неправда ли?
А вы как раз и запускаете открытие стандартным браузером ваших УРЛов

```
Intent shopIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/home.html"));
            startActivity(shopIntent);
```